# Why this oracle select as sql valid?

Tags: oracle

Please refer to the following oracle sql:

```sql
create table a(c1 number null, c2 number null);
select c1 as, c2 as from a;
```

We can see that `select <col_name> as` without `<col_alias>` is valid.

But from oracle sql reference
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/select_list.html the `as` part is: `expr [ [ AS ] c_alias ]`
which means:

- the total part: `[AS] c_alias` is optional.
- if we specify `[AS] c_alias`, the `AS` is optional, the `c_alias` is necessary.

But we only provide `AS` without `c_alias` and no error occurred.

Are there any oracle docs describe this?

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any oracle docs describe this?

The documentation [you quote](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/select_list.html) is the relevant documentation for the syntax of the list of expressions in the `SELECT` clause of a `SELECT` statement.

The only other relevant documentation would be noting that `AS` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612) and:

> You cannot use Oracle SQL reserved words as nonquoted identifiers.

---

Given the sample data:

```sql
create table a(c1 number null, c2 number null);
INSERT INTO a (c1, c2) VALUES (1, 2);
```

Then:

```sql
select c1 "AS", c2 "AS" from a;
```

Outputs:

| AS | AS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

and you can see that the column aliases are `AS` and the syntax will match `expr c_alias` rather than `expr AS c_alias`.

---

If you use the same expression without quoted identifiers:

```
select c1 AS, c2 AS from a;
```

Then the output is:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

The documentation [you quote](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/select_list.html) contains the expected syntax and:

- `expr AS c_alias` should fail to be matched as there is no `c_alias`; and
- `expr c_alias` should match the syntax but `AS` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612) so cannot be used as an (unquoted) identifier which you would expect to cause the query to fail.
- `expr` should not match as the `AS` reserved word is present.

Why it matches `expr c_alias` and then ignores the fact that `AS` is an invalid column alias and, instead, uses the original identifiers appears to be undocumented; it is probably a bug that should be reported to Oracle support.

---

If you try the query:

```sql
select c1 AS AS, c2 AS AS from a;
```

Then, as expected, it fails with the syntax error:

> ```
> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-sZA2xX4)